# Предложение: скрывать вопросы с меткой "статус-завершено" или "так задумано" с главной страницы

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, вопросы

Собственно, если такую метку поставили, значит вопрос решён, обсуждать нечего, можно освободить место под "открытые" вопросы на главной странице Meta ruSO.

Comment: Интересная мысль.

Comment: Может как раз наоборот? Метка "статус-завершено" должна по идее отмечать темы, в результате обсуждения которых участники достигли некоторого решения, что по идее должно быть доведено до сведения всех остальных посетителей Меты.

Comment: Что на мейнпаге MRuSO нет ландинга для бизнесов с промоушеном тимсов — это баг девелоперов компании, пофиксят soon™.

Comment: @Kyubey прекрасно.

Comment: @Kyubey, совершенно не понял вас. Вы о чём?

Comment: @mymedia [Мяу](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386505/293099).

Comment: Можно добавить любую метку в отслеживаемые и игнорируемые

Answer (score 5):

Может, кому-то важно, что выполнили его запрос или починили баг, который мешал жить. Пусть видят.

Если лично вы не хотите видеть такие вопросы, [добавьте в игнор](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be) метку [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be). После этого обновите страницу — теперь на ней не будет таких вопросов.

Comment: На место скрытого вопроса другой не подставится. Итог: расход пространства.

Comment: @edem надо просто страницу обновить после добавления метки в игнор.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ не срабатывает: просто также меняется "прозрачность" вопроса и всё, сам он остаётся на месте.

Comment: @edem в настройках есть 2 варианта игнорирования: затенять и скрывать. Нужен второй.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ а напомните, где эта настройка? Сходу не могу вспомнить.

Comment: @NickVolynkin справа на главной https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNHH2.png

Comment: Спасибо. Спрятали как эту настройку. Частично вопрос покрывает, но новые вопросы  на место скрытых всё равно не появятся. Впрочем их не так много на главной странице зачастую бывает.

Comment: Дополните ответ про эту настройку, помечу как решение.

Comment: @edem простите, совсем нет времени, работаю. Может, вы дополните?

Answer (score 4):

Я бы ещё понял, если бы там реально куча подобных вопросов всплыло. На моей памяти что-то такое было лишь когда по моим тревогам (и уже когда я сам стал модератором) вопросы по [локализация](/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) с этой меткой попали на главную. Но и то их там было не более 5.

Так что:

1. Я вообще проблемы не вижу.
2. [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be)/[статус-так-задумано](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be) показывает, что какое-то обсуждение/инициатива были реализованы/завершены. Поэтому, как @avp уже написал, тут ещё и информирующий аспект появляется.
3. Суть главной в том, что там отображаются **все** изменения, насколько я могу судить. Если будут исключены с главной изменения, связанные с этими метками, то это может привнести путаницу.